# For which values n is the matrix A negative definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I have a following matrix $M$:

\begin{bmatrix}
    n & 1 & 1  \\
    1 & n & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & -n 
  \end{bmatrix}

For which values $n$ (real numbers) is the matrix $A$ negative definite? I know that a matrix $A$ is negative definite iff $−A$ is positive definite. On the other hand, $A$ is positive definite iff for any $v \neq 0$, $v'Av > 0$.

However, how can I extend this?

Comment: Have you found the eigenvalue of $A$ (which depends on $n$)?

Comment: Sylvester's criterion for positive definiteness is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix is negative definite when the determinants of the principal minors satisfy $\Delta_1 <0, \Delta_2 > 0, \Delta_3 < 0$, which yields the conditions
$$
n < 0, \quad n^2-1 > 0, \quad n > 1.
$$

So, the matrix is never negative definite.

Note: We can assume that the determinant is nonzero, since $n=1$ produces an indefinite matrix.

Answer (score 2):

a negative definite matrix can never have a positive element on its diagonal, otherwise -- i.e. if $a_{j,j}\gt 0$ then
$\mathbf e_j^T A \mathbf e_j =a_{j,j}\gt 0$ so $A$ is not negative definite.

This leaves the only possibility of $n=0\implies A= \mathbf{11}^T -I$ which  has signature of $(1,2)$ -- i.e. PD for the subspace $W=\{\alpha\mathbf 1\}$ and negative definite on $W^\perp$.

So $A$ is never negative definite.

(alternative finish: prove a symmetric matrix that is negative (or positive) definite with a zero on diagonal position $j$ implies column $j$ and row $j$ are identically zero.)